# Posting to Facebook on behalf of the user: how to handle token expiration?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing a connect with Facebook/Twitter/... functionality on a website. The idea is that once a user connects his account with the external services our website could post messages on behalf of the user.

With Twitter there is no problem as the OAuth access_token doesn't expire. But with FB it does expire every two months, when the user logouts, changes password or explictly deauthorizes the app.

How should I handle the token expiration? For me it would be ideal if I could refresh the token automatically without bothering the user, but unless I've missed something it seems there isn't any way of doing this. So, right now I've two ideas:

- The less akward way: every time the user logins to the website check if the tokens have expired and notify the user that she has too reauthorize the app.
- The more akward way: every time the "post to social networks" event triggers in our website, check if the tokens have expired and ask the user to reauthorize.

The first option would be easier to implement and cleaner to the user.

So, how are you handling this situations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that I'll trye the first option:

- User logs in
- The server checks if the user has already a Facebook token, if so:
- Check if it's still a valid token. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/
- If the token expired NOT because the user deauthorized the app BUT because the other cases we redirect the user to the OAuth endpoint.

I'll give it a try and update this answer if there is more to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is actually interacting with your website, you should be getting a fresh `access_token` (read below). If you perform *offline* tasks related to the user using the Facebook API then you should be storing the `access_token` and their expiry dates. Then you need to handle expired access tokens and ask the user to interact with your app again and update your records.

You should refer to this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/#step3). Also you should be reading the [Extending Access Tokens document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/):

> **Step 2. Refreshing Long-lived User Access Tokens**
>
> At any point, *you can generate a new long-lived token by repeating the
>   original auth flow*, obtaining a new short-lived token and then
>   performing the same exchange as above. In some cases, this newer
>   long-lived token can be identical to the previous one, but we do not
>   guarantee this will be true and your app shouldn't depend upon it.